# How do I get the email address from Python 3 LinkedIn API?

Tags: python-3.x, linkedin-api

I am using this python3 Linkedin API:

https://github.com/DEKHTIARJonathan/python3-linkedin#production-authentication

I have 4 permissions on my profile:
r_basicprofile
r_emailaddress
rw_company_admin
rw_share

Even though this API seems to have nearly everything, I can't figure out how to get a member's email address.

For example when I query my own profile, (through the .get_profile() function), I don't get my email address. I looked through the API code and there doesn't seem to be a way to get a profile's email address.

For people who've used this API, how do you get a profile's email address? Because I can't produce even my own profile's email address

Answer (score 0):

```
GET http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(email-address)
```

this api-call will give you a users email.